# convert comment in input string into uppercase

Tags: c#, substring, uppercase

how can i identify commented string input by user. suppose user has typed

```
> I am /*not working*/ right now.
```

So i want to convert the commented sub string `> /* not working*/` into uppercase. how can i do that in c#. converting is not a problem. the problem is how to identify comments? what to do in the if block??

```
   static void comment(string exp_string)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < exp_string.Length; i++)
        {
            if (exp_string[i] == 47 && exp_string[i + 1] == 42)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this method:

```
public static string CommentToUpper(string input)
{
    int index = input.IndexOf("/*");
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        int endIndex = input.LastIndexOf("*/");
        if (endIndex > index)
            return string.Format("{0}/*{1}*/{2}", 
                input.Substring(0, index), 
                input.Substring(index + 2, endIndex - index - 2).ToUpper(), 
                input.Substring(endIndex + 2));
        else
            return string.Format("{0}/*{1}", 
                input.Substring(0, index), 
                input.Substring(index + 2).ToUpper());
    }
    return input;
}
```

Use it in this way:

```
string output =  CommentToUpper("> I am /*not working*/ right now.");
Console.Write(output);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/9yqiOd)</kbd>

Comment: Novice, Why `Substring` and `IndexOf` are allowed but not Regex?

Comment: that is because i am learning to design a compiler and i have been asked to use either switch or if else structures to match strings with my regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you're restricted from using something as clean as Regular Expressions, look into using [String.SubString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx), and [String.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper.aspx).

I think it's silly that you're being restricted, but sometimes there's no other choice. Best of luck to you.

EDIT: Another thing to consider is using IndexOf(). I leave that up to you, however, to find in MSDN

Comment: -1 `I think it's silly`, *"why do you learn math, you won't be a mathematician'*

Comment: @I4V There may very well be a good reason to restrict access; there was very little explanation offered aside from "can't do that", so it felt silly to have an arbitrary limitation IMHO.